# Avoid security warning in IE in Rss viewer webpart

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-server, rss

I have a RSS viewer webpart inserted on a Sharepoint page which shows description of today's birthdays along with images. I am getting security warning in IE due to images( http://)
I wan to suppress that warning and also i want images to be displayed. If images are removed then there is no warning.
Any idea ?\
below is the xsl code I got from RSS webpart

```
<xsl:param name="rss_FeedLimit">5</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_ExpandFeed">false</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_LCID">1033</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_WebPartID">RSS_Viewer_WebPart</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_alignValue">left</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="rss_IsDesignMode">True</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="rss" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:rssFeed="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:RSSAggregatorWebPart" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rss1="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:atom2="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">
        <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate"/>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template match="rdf:RDF">
        <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="atom:feed">
        <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="atom2:feed">
        <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate">
        <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="channel/item"/>
        <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
        <div class="slm-layout-main" >            
        <div class="groupheader item medium">

                    <h4>                       
                     <Big>
                    <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(channel/link))}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="channel/title"/>
                    </a>
                    <xsl:text xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:whitespace-preserve="yes" xml:space="preserve"> </xsl:text>
                    <span style="color: #0066CC">:</span></Big>
                    </h4>
        </div>            
        <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.body">
            <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate.body">
        <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
        <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
            <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
            <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
            <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
            <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
                <div class="item link-item" >
                      <Big> <Big><a href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}">
                      <xsl:value-of select="title" /></a></Big> </Big>
                        <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
                            <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
                                <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
                            <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
                                <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                </div>                            
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>



<xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
        <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
        <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/><div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="{$rss_alignValue}" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};">
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- some RSS2.0 contain pubDate tag, some others dc:date -->
                <xsl:when test="string-length(pubDate) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:variable name="pubDateLength" select="string-length(pubDate) - 3" />
            <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(substring(pubDate,0,$pubDateLength),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(dc:date),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:if test="string-length(description) &gt; 0">
                <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                    <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                        <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="description"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                 -
                <xsl:text xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes" disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
```

```
            </xsl:if><br /><div class="description">

        </div>
    </div>
    </xsl:template>





    <xsl:template name="RDFMainTemplate" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
        <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="rss1:item"/>
        <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
        <div class="slm-layout-main" >
        <div class="groupheader item medium">
            <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(rss1:channel/rss1:link))}">
                <xsl:value-of select="rss1:channel/rss1:title"/>
            </a>
        </div>            
        <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate.body">
            <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="RDFMainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
        <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
        <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
            <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
            <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
            <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
            <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
                <div class="item link-item" >
                    <a href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" >
                        <xsl:value-of select="rss1:title"/>
                    </a>
                    <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
                            <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate.description">
                                <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
                            <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate.description">
                                <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:if>
                </div>
    </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="RDFMainTemplate.description" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
        <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
        <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/>
    <div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="{$rss_alignValue}" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};">
        <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(dc:date),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
            <xsl:if test="string-length(rss1:description) &gt; 0">
                <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                    <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                        <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="rss1:description"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:variable>
                 - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </xsl:if>
        <div class="description">
            <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(rss1:link))}">More...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="ATOMMainTemplate" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
        <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="atom:entry"/>
        <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
        <div class="slm-layout-main" >
        <div class="groupheader item medium">
            <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom:link/@href))}">
                <xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/>
            </a>
        </div>            
        <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate.body">
            <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ATOMMainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
        <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
        <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
            <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
            <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
            <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
            <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
                        <div class="item link-item" >
                            <a href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" >
                                <xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/>
                            </a>
                            <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                        </div>
    </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ATOMMainTemplate.description" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
        <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
        <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/>
    <div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="{$rss_alignValue}" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};">
    <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(atom:updated),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(atom:summary) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                        <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                            <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom:summary"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                     - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(atom:content) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                        <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                            <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom:content"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                     - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        <div class="description">
            <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom:link/@href))}">More...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ATOM2MainTemplate" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
        <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="atom2:entry"/>
        <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
        <div class="slm-layout-main" >
        <div class="groupheader item medium">                
            <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom2:link/@href))}">
                <xsl:value-of select="atom2:title"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.body">
            <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
        <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
        <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
            <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
            <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
            <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
            <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
                 <div class="item link-item" >
                            <a href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" >
                                <xsl:value-of select="atom2:title"/>
                            </a>
                        <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
                            <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.description">
                                <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
                            <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.description">
                                <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                </div>
    </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.description" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
        <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
        <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/>
    <div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="{$rss_alignValue}" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};">
        <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(atom2:updated),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(atom2:summary) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                        <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                            <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom2:summary"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                     - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="string-length(atom2:content) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                        <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                            <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom2:content"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                     - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        <div class="description">
            <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom2:link/@href))}">More...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="GetSafeHtml">
        <xsl:param name="Html"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$rss_IsDesignMode = 'True'">
                 <xsl:value-of select="$Html"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                 <xsl:value-of select="rssaggwrt:MakeSafe($Html)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Is your site running under SSL?

Comment: yes correct...its a SharePoint site..Https...!!